# how to zip all Azure blob in container with date time postfix

Tags: zip, azure-blob-storage

I want to zip all blob in the container with the current date and time.
Anyone tried, please help

Comment: Your description is too simple, please update it for more details, such as  to do the zip task at where, whether in programming or just  manually, and so on. These information will help us to post the solution for satisfying your needs as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the simplest solution to zip all Azure blobs in a container is to mount the container via `blobfuse` (GitHub repo [Azure/azure-storage-fuse](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse)) to a directory of the filesystem of Linux machine like Azure Linux VM, then you can manually use Linux command like `tar`, `gzip`, `zip` to zip these files in your mounted container to a file named by yourself with a postfix from command `` `date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`.zip `` like on local filesytem. Please refer to the [wiki page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/wiki) to know how to use `blobfuse`.